# WPF window doesn't get focus

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I'm having a problem where my main application window keeps the focus after a non-modal window is initiated from it.  It seems at first glance that it might be the hollow windows issue with WPF (we use transparent backgrounds), but the window doesn't even have focus at all (this.IsFocused STAYS false).

As soon as you click on the window, the click goes through to the main window behind it.  After which, if the window is activated from the windows taskbar, the window has focus, can be activated, and accepts all clicks.

I've tried taking focus from the window itself, with API calls, trying to simulate the clicks, the whole toot.

What I think might be happening is that somewhere, something else is keeping focus on the main window once the child window is generated (this is NOT an MDI environment).  Is there some application that allows me to check which WPF element has focus, or somehow makes it possible for me to trace the focus in the application?  I've tried snoop, and it doesn't play well with our app (makes it fall over).

Any other ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you write a minimal app which demonstrate the issue and post the code here.

Comment: The problem is that it's only happening in one or two forms of ours, and not the others - there's also no distinguishable property or characteristic which seperates those that have this issue and those that don't.  I'll try and see if I can replicate it in a simple app.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a known issue with RPC services, it cannot be fixed and it is not your code fault. Reboot your system and try again this scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the input Eugene -  but trust me, I've tried rebooting.  There is also no RPC happening when the problematic form is opened.

Comment: We're waiting for you sample app and steps to reproduce. Really interesting problem.